# Window disappears for a short time on setContentView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ikimageview

here is my code:

```
- (void)showEditBackground
{
    editBackgroundController = [[EditBackgroundVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"BackgroundVC" bundle:nil];
    [window setContentView:editBackgroundController.view];
}
```

the problem is:
If I call this code the window is going shortly transparent.
After this very short time the window comes back with the view loaded.
It looks like a flash.

This only happens if editBackgroundControllers view has a IKImageView as one subview.
Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here my solution to this problem:
on some views the 'Core Animation Layer' in IB was 'on'.